# Joomla! Username Greeting

Tags: php, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

How can I take advantage of the Joomla! 1.6 login variable that displays the greeting of an authenticated user? In other words. Let's say I wanted to greet the user somewhere else how can I do so? What files do i have to include into my extension and what variable or what exactly produces this greeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to access the User object. I haven't tested this, but it should work -

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$name = $user->get('name');
```

Substitute username for name if you need the login name instead of the real name.